# Phoenix 1.3 flash not showing up

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, flash-message

My `put_flash(conn)` and `get_flash(conn)` methods are behaving strangely; when I use redirect everything works fine, but nothing shows up when I try to add `flash_msg` in the controller behind.

Looks like the messages are stored in `:phoenix_flash` instead of `:plug_session`; any idea on what's wrong there?

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Welcome : info")
    |> put_flash(:error, "Welcome : error")
    render conn, "index.html"
  end

private: %{EverlearnWeb.Router => {[], %{}}, 
:phoenix_action => :index,
:phoenix_controller => EverlearnWeb.PageController,
:phoenix_endpoint => EverlearnWeb.Endpoint,
:phoenix_flash => %{"error" => "Welcome : error", "info" => "Welcome : info"},
:phoenix_layout => {EverlearnWeb.LayoutView, :app},
:phoenix_pipelines => [:browser], :phoenix_router => EverlearnWeb.Router,
:phoenix_view => EverlearnWeb.PageView,
:plug_session => %{"_csrf_token" => "xxx",
 "phoenix_flash" => %{"info" => "Welcome back Thibaut, your are signed in !"},
 "user_id" => 1}, :plug_session_fetch => :done}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pipe your `conn` that you put your flash messages into the `render` function:

```
conn
|> put_flash(:info, "Welcome : info")
|> put_flash(:error, "Welcome : error")
|> render("index.html")
```

In your approach you added flash messages to a `conn`, but in `render` you are using non-updated one that has been passed to your action.

Other approach would be to assign to a `conn` if you wish to pass the data correctly to `render`:

```
conn =
  conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "Welcome : info")
  |> put_flash(:error, "Welcome : error")

render conn, "index.html"
```

Comment: Thanks ! How could I miss it... 
Just for information, why then does it appear in private.phoenix_flash ?

Comment: Great question, unfortunately, I'm afraid I'm unable to comment on the implementation details...